# Python Multiprocessing Logging

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I'm currently attempting to implement logging for both informational and error messages while utilizing pool.imap_unordered in my code. I've been following an approach outlined at https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-multiprocessing-logging/#multiprocessing-logging-in-python.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mp
import logging
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener
import datetime
import time
import os


class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_logger()

        self.logger.info("some text...")
        self.logger.info("some text...")
        self.logger.info(" ")

    def my_logger(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("test")
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # Create a log file name
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        log_file_name = "file_log_{}.txt".format(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))

        # Create a FileHandler
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_name)
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        log_format_file = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
        file_handler.setFormatter(log_format_file)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        # Create a StreamHandler
        screen_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        screen_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        log_format_screen = logging.Formatter("%(message)s")
        screen_handler.setFormatter(log_format_screen)
        self.logger.addHandler(screen_handler)

        def Process_init(self, q):
            queue_handler = QueueHandler(q)
            logger = logging.getLogger()
            logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            logger.addHandler(queue_handler)

        def evaluate(self, a, b):
            result = a + b
            logging.info("Process/function with PID {}".format(os.getpid()))
            return result

        def process_row(self, index_row_pair):
            # Unpack the tuple
            index, row = index_row_pair

            features_dict = self.evaluate(a=row["a"], b=row["b"])
            logging.info("some text...")

            return features_dict

        def run_imap_unordered(self, df):
            logging.info("some text...")

            mp_queue = mp.Queue()
            queue_listener = QueueListener(mp_queue, self.logger)
            queue_listener.start()

            with mp.Pool(4, self.Process_init, [mp_queue]) as pool:
                results_list = list(
                    tqdm(
                        pool.imap_unordered(self.process_row, df.iterrows()),
                        total=df.shape[0],
                        desc="Processing...",
                    )
                )
            queue_listener.stop()
            return results_list

        def main_func(self, df_path):
            # Read input CSV file into a DataFrame
            df = pd.read_csv(df_path)

            start_time = time.time()
            results_list = self.run_imap_unordered(df)
            process_duration_imap_unordered = time.time() - start_time
            self.logger.info(f"Time spent for run_imap_unordered: {process_duration_imap_unordered:.4f} seconds")

            features_df = pd.DataFrame(results_list)
            features_df.to_csv("path to csv output", index=None)

            self.logger.info("Results are saved in " + "path to csv output")
            self.logger.info("Done!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_obj = test()
    df_path = "path to a csv file"
    test_obj.main_func(df_path)
```

I'm uncertain if my implementation is accurate. I'd like to understand how to effectively log messages from functions that are executed during multiprocessing, such as process_row or evaluate. Should I use logging.info("some text..."), or is it more appropriate to utilize self.logger.info("some text...")?

Furthermore, I'd appreciate clarification on whether it's correct to use self.logger.info("some text...") within the **init**(self) and main_func sections of my code.

Thank you for your assistance.

**Update:**
Perhaps it would be more effective to present the question using the code shown in the provided link

```
import multiprocessing
import logging
import os
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener

def func(arg):
    logging.info('Process/function with argument {} and PID {}'.format(arg, os.getpid()))

def Process_init(q):
    queue_handler = QueueHandler(q)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(queue_handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('Main Started')
    mp_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    lg_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

    lg_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s - %(process)s - %(message)s"))

    queue_listener = QueueListener(mp_queue, lg_handler)
    queue_listener.start()

    process_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2, Process_init, [mp_queue])
    process_pool.map(func, [1, 2])
    process_pool.close()
    process_pool.join()

    queue_listener.stop()
    print ('Main Ended')
```

If I intend to log messages in the main function above before invoking the queue_listener, should I utilize lg_handler.info or would it be more appropriate to use logging.info? Moreover, within the func(arg) context, would it be accurate to utilize logging.info instead of directly calling the logger itself, i.e., lg_handler.info?

Apologies for any confusion in my explanation.

Answer (score -1):

<del>You have to use `logging.info`</del> Just call `logger.info` with a logger created on module level.

You can read in the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) that the call to `logging.getLogger()` will always return the reference to the root (system wide) logger. So it doesn't matter if it is inside a module or a function running on a separate process/thread. Keeping the object in a class member as with `self.logger` is not necessary as you cannot initialize more than one instance of the logger anyway.

Here is a minimum example that works correctly at my machine (modified from [here](https://www.jamesfheath.com/2020/06/logging-in-python-while-multiprocessing.html)):

```
import logging
import multiprocessing

logger = logging.getLogger()
fh = logging.FileHandler("my_log.log", encoding="utf-8")
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

data_to_process = [1, 2, 3]


def my_function(num):
    logger = logging.getLogger()  # actually not required but worsk still the same
    logger.info("hello from inside process")
    return num


def run():
    num_processes = 3
    with multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes) as pool:
        logger.info("hello from before process")
        for result in pool.map(my_function, data_to_process):
            logger.info(f"result of process: {result}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Yielding the following `my_log`-file:

```
hello from before process
hello from inside process
hello from inside process
hello from inside process
result of process: 1
result of process: 2
result of process: 3
```

Comment: well, no, `getLogger()` will return the same object only in the same process. And there can be multiple instances of a logger.

Comment: Thank you @RaJa for the informative reply. So there is no need to use QueueHandler and QueueListener to prevent two processes from writing to the log file at the same time?

Comment: No, you don't. It seems that when you use the root logger that it will take care of the file handling itself.

Comment: I'm sorry for repeating, but I really want to understand this topic. In the link you kindly shared, it says that 'Unfortunately, logging to a single file from multiple processes is not supported, and you will end up with some frustrating bugs.'. The author then talks about a different method using Queue-Handler to manage the logging. Why did they choose to do it this way?

Comment: I can't actually answer that. I've tested my code in Windows and Linux (wsl). It runs without problems in both tests. But the example is pretty short and race conditions might not appear.

Comment: Just tested this with multiple calls to the logger per sub-process. No problems there.

Comment: Mark as solved if it is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Yeah sure no problem - I will do that. However, I will leave this issue open for a few days before closing just in case anyone wants to jump on it.

Comment: Hello, I wanted to provide a quick update. I've implemented your approach with a large dataset, but it appears that the logs I've received don't exhibit the expected level of consistency. I'll investigate this issue to determine if there might be any issues with my code.